# Difference between "how you are" and "how you were"

Tags: american-english

I heard in a talkshow that someone said.

"I wanted to see how you **were** doing after the operation"

My question is what the difference is to:

"I wanted to see how you **are** doing after the operation"

Can someone explain that? Thanks

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sounds like an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The second sentence here

> I wanted to see how you are doing after the operation.

would usually be addressed to someone still in the period expected for recuperation. Hence the '. . . how you *are* doing . . .' . The 'wanted' may seem illogical if not actually untrue, 'want' appearing more appropriate, but there is a pragmatic, hedging, effect; 'I want' sounds more akin to a demand.

The first sentence

> I wanted to see how you were doing after the operation.

is equally acceptable and *could* mean exactly the same thing, with slightly more cushioning ('how you were doing' being slightly less threatening, distancing possible ongoing illness) – and be used in exactly the same situation – but it could equally refer to a past situation: "I wanted to see how you were doing after the operation, but I was in the middle of Borneo that year, and couldn't contact the British authorities"

Comment: A third possibility is _how you've been doing since the operation_